# How can I get value from aria-rowcount, not visible on page, Protractor

Tags: protractor

How can I get value from aria-rowcount, I need that 517 value.

I attached image also `<div class="dx-datagrid dx-gridbase-container" role="grid" aria-label="Data grid" aria-rowcount="517" aria-colcount="4">`

```
async getNrOfTables() {
    console.log(' ### => Get the number of tables ');
    BrowserUtil.waitForElement(this.nrOfTables);
    await browser.sleep(2000);
    let j = this.nrOfTables.getAttribute('aria-rowcount')
     console.log(' ### => The number of tables ', j);
     return this;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54dKJ.png)

Comment: you are missing await this.nrOfTables.getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution to get the attribute value

```
async getNrOfTables(){
//if you are using any waits then use here
let j = await this.nrOfTables.getAttribute('aria-rowcount');
console.log("Number of tables: " + j);
return j;
}
```